# how to: list all possible permutations of two columns of text in Openoffice Calc or Excel

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to do the following:

I have a sheet with 2 columns of cells with text input.
Now, I would like to generate all permutations, and preferably paste them in a separate sheet.
Is there anyone who knows how to do this? (And who has some spare time left.. :D)

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Fred Schnitt

Comment: You want a nested loop. Do you know Excel's VBA or OpenOffice's StarBasic?  Also, if you're using OpenOffice, I recommend LibreOffice as an upgrade.

Comment: Just to makes sure that the problem is understood, have you figured out how many permutations you are talking about when you say "all permuations?"

Comment: Just to makes sure that the problem is understood, have you figured out how many permutations you are talking about when you say "all permuations?"

Let's look at this case, of three rows:

  a | d
  b | e
  c | f

If you are talking about the pairings in each row, we can keep the first column fixed and just permute the second column.  Reversing pairs is easy.  Would this be an acceptable result for all permutations:

 a | d | d | e | e | f | f
 b | e | f | d | f | d | e
 c | f | e | f | d | e | d

That's six permutations for only 3 terms (d e f).  It gets worse quickly.  Is this the goal?

Comment: @tony: thanks i'm gonna check out LibreOffice; on the web, it seems the community prefers this suite over openoffice; probably for a reason :)

Answer (score 0):

Comment formatting doesn't allow two-dimensional layout.  Let's see if this works better.

Just to makes sure that the problem is understood, have you figured out how many permutations you are talking about when you say "all permuations?"

Let's look at this case, of three rows:

a | d

b | e

c | f

If you are talking about the pairings in each row, we can keep the first column fixed and just permute the second column.  Reversing pairs is easy.  Would this be an acceptable result for all permutations:

a | d | d | e | e | f | f

b | e | f | d | f | d | e

c | f | e | f | d | e | d

That's six permutations for only 3 terms (d e f).  It gets worse quickly.  Is this the goal?

Comment: Hi orcmid, I think my explanation might be incorrect for what I'm trying to achieve. So I'll try again.

Comment: Hi orcmid, I think my explanation might be incorrect for what I'm trying to achieve. So I'll try again. (btw I have combined my two columns into one to make this easier, I hope) In total I have 40 cells with text. For example. A1John A2Claire A3Barack A4Etc.. I want to list all possible combinations of max 2 cells. For example JohnClaire JohnBarack ClaireJohn ClaireBarack BarackJohn BarackClaire. That's 40*39=1560 right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have objects(data choices whether letters, words or text).
You would take the quantity multiplied by the (quantity -1), IE 40*39

Now in your example if say JohnClaire and ClaireJohn counts as repetition
and one must be eliminated, then the math result should be.
(quantity * quantity -1)/(2).That result should be 780.

It all depends if the example of JohnClaire and Claire John is considered the same.

I wish I had the code to list this scenario for whether using text or numbers.